# What kind of "locking" barrel connector is this?

Tags: power-supply, connector

I am looking for a replacement for a barrel connector; this is a locking connector (PN: PWRS-14000-260R for a Motorola FX9500 RFID Reader Country of origin: CHINA) however the locking 'fins' (for lack of a better description) are located on the sleeve instead of more commonly (?) nubs on the plastic tip

Even knowing the plug specifics (2.1mm x 5.5mm inline plug (Female)) and providing measurements of these 'fins'(are about .5mm tall x 2.7mm wide and stick out of the barrel sleeve about 7.5mm from the end of the plastic tip) and contacting Digi-Key and Condor Electronics with pictures, I am unable to find anything on this plug type.

I am beginning to think that this is a proprietary plug made specifically for Motorola by LEI and Motorola is NOT good about providing vendor info (I'm finding out).

Any ideas on what this particular connector is referred to as and if they can be found anywhere commercially?

Barrel front:

[image]

Barrel side:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I've seen the same type of connector used on the 12V DC power supply of a Sarian 3G GSM router. We had to get spare power cables directly from the supplier of the router.

Comment: http://ftp1.digi.com/support/images/KC-300476.pdf

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the company in the next link sell these connectors:
http://www.cliffuk.co.uk/products/dcconnectors/

the specific datasheet:
http://www.cliffuk.co.uk/products/dcconnectors/DCPlugSocketLockable.pdf

You can check if they have an distributor in your country and get it from there.
Hope this helps you!

We were also searching for this because off a Motorola FX7500 RFID reader.
Have a nice day!
Dennis Tessels.

Answer (score 3):

Condor Electronics came through for the win, their part "CA205LP-18IN-S/T-WWP-18AWG-105C" appears to fit the bill after viewing pictures.

They do not have this part on their website but the image they supplied (no tech sheets unfortunately) appears promising.

[image]

Maybe I shouldn't be answering this question without having the piece in hand but I have good feels about it

Answer (score 1):

You probably already found this, but if not, try Kycon part number KLDX-PA-0202-A-LT.

Comment: One line answers are at risk of being downvoted or deleted. You have an upvote, but a more detailed answer might have gained you more votes. (how it might work, why it might work, cost, plus a link to a pdf if possible)